# Center text vertically in image in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I have the following simple PHP function to get the coordinates of a text box to centre it horizontally and vertically.

```
$box_coo = imagettfbbox(25, 0, 'arial.ttf', $string);
$box_width = $box_coo[2] - $box_coo[0];
$box_height = $box_coo[7] - $box_coo[1];
```

This centers horizontally well but not vertically at all. Aren't the chosen Y coordinates correct?

Thanks

Comment: yes, edited, but this is not the problem anyway

Comment: actually saw this questionm before but still it's not vertically aligned well

Comment: The answer over there says that you want to use `abs($box_coo[5]-$box_coo[1])`

Comment: tried it but the text is pushed up more towards top